# What is the grammatical function of "Emerging as it does..."

Tags: participles

> **Emerging as it does from a basis of truth**, it is bound to...

What is the function of the bonded part in the sentence above? Is it a participle phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a partiple phrase.  The participle "Emerging" is modified by to prepositional phrases "as it does" (which is idiomatic, and merely asserts the truth of the phrase) and "from a basis of truth".